# React Material UI, how do I make mobile friendly selects?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am working on a `React` project and I am using `Material UI`.

Versions:

```
├─ react@15.6.1
├─ material-ui@0.19.4
```

I have in my code a component that makes use of [Select Field](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) component.

My code looks something like this:

```
<SelectField some_props>
    {some_list.map(() => {return <MenuItem other_props/>})}
</SelectField>
```

On a desktop, this looks very good. However, I would like to get the native mobile select. The rolling one.

Basically, this:

[image: Roll select]

How do I get a mobile friendly rolling select with Material UI?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just render a native select if the user is on mobile? There's lots of answers on how to detect if someone is on a mobile, and then just use a `<select />` instead.

Comment: I will try that. Do you have any tips on testing this? I added the simple <select> example from w3schools, but on the chrome console, with the device set to mobile, it still looks like a dropdown. Rebuilding and deploying to test seems like a pain.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example component which uses `react-device-detect`. If the user `isMobile`, the native select/options are rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import {isMobile} from 'react-device-detect';

import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

const ExampleSelect = () => {

    const value = null;
    const onChange = (e) => console.log(e.target.value);
    const options = [
        {value: 1, label: 'Option 1'},
        {value: 2, label: 'Option 2'},
        {value: 3, label: 'Option 3'}
    ];

    return (

        <FormControl>
            <InputLabel>
                Options
            </InputLabel>
            <Select
                native={isMobile}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
            >
                {options.map(option => (
                    isMobile ? (
                        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
                    ) : (
                        <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
                    )
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>

    )
}    

export default ExampleSelect;
```